# Two-dimensional Int array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Is it the easiest way to declare two-dimensional `Int` array with specified size in Kotlin?

```
val board = Array(n, { IntArray(n) })
```

Comment: `this.data = Array(rowCount) { IntArray(colCount) } `
the semantic changed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here are source code for new top-level functions to create 2D arrays.  When Kotlin is missing something, extend it.  Then add [YouTrack issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) for things you want to suggest and track the status.  Although in this case they aren't much shorter than above, at least provides a more obvious naming for what is happening.

```
public inline fun <reified INNER> array2d(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int, noinline innerInit: (Int)->INNER): Array<Array<INNER>> 
    = Array(sizeOuter) { Array<INNER>(sizeInner, innerInit) }
public fun array2dOfInt(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int): Array<IntArray> 
    = Array(sizeOuter) { IntArray(sizeInner) }
public fun array2dOfLong(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int): Array<LongArray> 
    = Array(sizeOuter) { LongArray(sizeInner) }
public fun array2dOfByte(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int): Array<ByteArray> 
    = Array(sizeOuter) { ByteArray(sizeInner) }
public fun array2dOfChar(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int): Array<CharArray> 
    = Array(sizeOuter) { CharArray(sizeInner) }
public fun array2dOfBoolean(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int): Array<BooleanArray> 
    = Array(sizeOuter) { BooleanArray(sizeInner) }
```

And usage:

```
public fun foo() {
    val someArray = array2d<String?>(100, 10) { null }
    val intArray = array2dOfInt(100, 200)
}
```

Comment: Can you give some documentation's links? I can found any reference and Idea kotlin plug in seams do not resolve it.

Comment: The functions and their source code are in my answer @Micheled'Amico ... they are not part of the stdlib.

Comment: Sorry I was too lazy when I reed your answer. .... But I tried it and generic version doesn't work. Even it seams correct and it should return a `Array(Array<Something>)` at run time I receive `java.lang.ClassCastException: [[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Something;` exception. Moreover IMHO a better signature can be `array2d(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int, init: (Int, Int)->INNER)`. I'll file a question to understand what is wrong your function definition.

Comment: You already meet this issue at http://stackoverflow.com/q/34514861/4101725 ... I open a issue on You Track https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10555

Answer (score 12):

Currently this is the easiest way, we will extend the standard library with appropriate functions later

Comment: Do I have other methods to declare two-dimensional Int array Now?

Comment: It's 1.1.3 now. Does it up to date?

Comment: Are there any new methods to declare two-dimensional Int array available in 2024?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your given code is the easiest way to declare a two-dimensional array.

Below, I am giving you an example of 2D array initialization & printing.

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    var num = 100

    // Array Initialization
    var twoDArray = Array(4, {IntArray(3)})
    for(i in 0..twoDArray.size - 1) {
        var rowArray = IntArray(3)
        for(j in 0..rowArray.size - 1) {
            rowArray[j] = num++
        }
        twoDArray[i] = rowArray
    }

    // Array Value Printing
    for(row in twoDArray) {
        for(j in row) {
            print(j)
            print(" ")
        }
        println("")
    }

}
```

Comment: But you don't need `var rowArray = IntArray(3)`. Because the second parameter of `Array(...)` initializes each array element. So you could do `val rowArray = twoDArray[i]`.