# How to simplify the assignment of mutable list in a mutable list

Tags: list, kotlin

So I am doing a text-based game in Kotlin with classes. I need to know is there any other way than doing the code below. Like for example I want it to do something like

```
val game:MutableList<MutableList<Char>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf(' '*6)*7)
```

Game:

```
private val game:MutableList<MutableList<Char>> = mutableListOf(
            mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
            mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
            mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
            mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
            mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
            mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
            mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ')
    )
```

Comment: You might find nested arrays easier to initialize, if your lists would have fixed lengths anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27512636/4465208

Comment: @zsmb13 I actually do not know what is the difference between arrays and lists. Since I came from Python, most people call it list. So I use list.

Comment: Arrays are fixed size containers, while lists are dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MutableList(7) { MutableList(6) { ' ' } }
```

using [`inline fun <T> MutableList(size: Int, init: (index: Int) -> T): MutableList<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html). Other collections have similar factory functions.

Answer (score 1):

*generateSequence* can be used to create a sequence of elements using a function. *take()* limits to sequence to a number of elements and *toMutableList()* turns it into a list.

```
private val game: MutableList<MutableList<Char>> = 
  generateSequence { generateSequence { ' ' }.take(6).toMutableList() }
    .take(7).toMutableList()
```