# How can we create array of array list in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
var l=Array<ArrayList<Int>()>(5){};
```

I tried the above code but, it gave me a compile time error.
What is the correct way to achieve this?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-dimensional Int array in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512636/two-dimensional-int-array-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the full syntax to do this:

```
val l: Array<ArrayList<Int>> = Array<ArrayList<Int>>(5) { ArrayList<Int>() }
```

You can simplify this in a couple of ways, for example you can leave out the type on the left:

```
val l = Array<ArrayList<Int>>(5) { ArrayList<Int>() }
```

And then you can also leave out some more of the types, either of these ways:

```
val l = Array<ArrayList<Int>>(5) { ArrayList() }
val l = Array(5) { ArrayList<Int>() }
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped me.